# Query XML data in SQL Server 2016 database

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, xpath, xquery, sql-server-2016

I have XML data stored in a SQL Server 2016 database that I need to query a date range in a stored procedure around the `PROJECT_END` to return the `application_ID`'s

```
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <APPLICATION_ID>3012448</APPLICATION_ID>
    <ACTIVITY>D23</ACTIVITY>
    <ADMINISTERING_IC>NU</ADMINISTERING_IC>
    <APPLICATION_TYPE>1</APPLICATION_TYPE>
    <ARRA_FUNDED xsi:nil="true" />
    <BUDGET_START>01/01/1985</BUDGET_START>
    <BUDGET_END>12/31/1985</BUDGET_END>
    <FOA_NUMBER xsi:nil="true" />
    <PROJECT_START>01/01/1985</PROJECT_START>
    <PROJECT_END>12/31/1987</PROJECT_END>
  </row>
</PROJECTS>
```

I have the select part but can't seem to query based upon the date range using `PROJECT_END`. Also would `BETWEEN` work?

```
SELECT 
    nref.value('APPLICATION_ID[1]', 'Int') APPLICATION_ID                         
FROM 
    STAGING
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('/PROJECTS/row') AS r(nref)
WHERE
    nref.value('PROJECT_END[1]', 'varchar(max)') > '1/1/1987' 
    AND nref.value('PROJECT_END[1]', 'varchar(max)') < '1/1/1990'
```

I have no control over the formatting of the date fields, unless I can convert it on the fly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a date value - why don't you **treat it like that?** Don't convert this value to a `nvarchar(max)` - it's a **date**, so convert it to `DATE` instead! Doing that, your query should work just fine.

Also, I'd suggest to *always* use the adapted **ISO-8601** format for specifying dates as string literals - e.g. the format `YYYYMMDD` (no slashes, nothing) - this works for **all** language/date format settings:

```
SELECT 
    nref.value('APPLICATION_ID[1]', 'INT') APPLICATION_ID                         
FROM 
    STAGING
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('/PROJECTS/row') AS r(nref)
WHERE
    nref.value('PROJECT_END[1]', 'DATE') > '19870101' 
    AND nref.value('PROJECT_END[1]', 'DATE') < '19900101'
```

Comment: The OP states: *I have no control over the formatting of the date fields*

Comment: The usage of `value('..','DATE')` relys on the system's culture settings. If this is other the `DATEFORMAT MDY` this conversion will break...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT 
    nref.value('APPLICATION_ID[1]', 'Int') APPLICATION_ID                         
FROM 
    STAGING
CROSS APPLY
    XMLData.nodes('/PROJECTS/row') AS r(nref)
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE,nref.value('(PROJECT_END/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),101) >= {d'1987-01-01'} 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,nref.value('(PROJECT_END/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),101) < {d'1990-01-01'};
```

Some background:

Your date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) you need the format code `101` to parse it correctly.

Within XML one should **really never use culture dependant date/time formats**! So the clear advise was: Change the XML and use `ISO8601`! But - as you state in your query - this is not under your control...

The reason, why your alphanumerical comparisson did not work properly was probably related to `> '1/1/1987'` which should have been `> '01/01/1987'`. Even if this might work, you should try to remain a typed valued in the appropriate type.

Stating a date literally has several options. I prefer the `ODBC` syntax, other people will prefer `'19870101'` (unseparated)...

#### update

In your query I assume, that the original XML consists of several `<row>` nodes (due to your call to `.nodes('/PROJECTS/row')`. If the dateformat was specified correctly, you could add an `XQuery predicate` to this. The result was a derived table with the wanted `<row>` nodes only. But you have to rely on the system's culture setting, which is evil. Therefore your query has to read the whole lot into a derived table, just to filter some of them out (calling expensive parse operations)... Double penalty...

Comment: The original/original xml consists of tens of thousands of rows per year that when you add up all of the years it is close to 3 million.  I have parse each years worth of xml data and have stored it as a single row in the database.  After I have pulled out the rows innerxml I added back the project and row nodes before saving it to the database.  Would it have been better if I just started with the APPLICATION_ID node? or keep the row node and omit the PROJECTS node?

Comment: And yes I don't have any control over the date format and depending on the hosting (right now mine, but not always) I don't have any control over the systems culture settings.

Comment: @user1314159 Do you have a really good reason, to keep this lot of data within XML? Why don't you store your data in a normal table? XML is not meant to store such a big amount of **actively used data**.